# Get-AzureRmConsumptionUsageDetail limited response to 1000 items

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I've discovered this azure PS command [Get-AzureRmConsumptionUsageDetail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.consumption/get-azurermconsumptionusagedetail) that as per docs is able to *"get usage details of the subscription"*.

I performed some tests on my MSDN account with success. When tried with the Enterprise account (with many more resources) I've seen that it is always returning a max of 1000 items in all cases.

I tried to set `-MaxCount` to a higher than 1000 value without success.

The only workaround I see is try to identify all the resources in my subscription and query each one with the hope that no one individually has more than a thousand entries. Bad news is that I cannot do that for deleted items.

This behavior is not mentioned on the MS docs page so, any idea how this command should be properly used?

Answer (score 0):

To partially solve my problem I developed a quick and dirty script that is able to ask for all the current subscription resources and then iterate through all them to get the billing details. It should be strange for a single resource to overpass the 1000 rows limit as resources are usually billed per day.

The drawbacks are the amount of api calls it has to perform and thus the time as well as that deleted resources are not included.

```
$resources = Get-AzureRmResource

Write-Output "Found $($resources.Count) in the subscription"

$consumption = @()

$i = $resources.Count
foreach($resource in $resources) { 
    $consumption += Get-AzureRmConsumptionUsageDetail -InstanceId $resource.ResourceId
    $i--
    Write-Output "$i - $($resource.ResourceId)"
}

$consumption | Group-Object InstanceId | %{ 
    New-Object psobject -Property @{
            ResourceGroup = ([regex]::Match($_.Name, ".*\/resource[gG]roups\/(.*?)\/.*$")).Groups[1].Value.ToUpper(); 
            Cost = ($_.Group | Measure-Object PretaxCost -Sum).Sum
    } 
} | Group-Object ResourceGroup | %{ 
    New-Object psobject -Property @{
            ResourceGroup = $_.Name; 
            Total = ($_.Group | Measure-Object Cost -Sum).Sum
    }
} | Export-Csv cost_report.csv
```